# When will a new emission driving cycle be implemented?

Tags: emissions, driving, testing, drive-cycle

For emssion tests, they have used the NEDC driving cyle here in Europe for quite a while now. I'm not sure about America and Asia, but i believe they use similar driving cycles. After the emission issue with VW and many more car brands, the need for a new driving cycle arose. I believe they had planned that before already, but that issue sped things up quite a bit i have heard. So the old NEDC cycle will be replaced soon by a new driving cycle. Ive heard multiple sources expecting it to happen this or the next year. They expect that the WLTP cycle will be used, but it could also be another cycle. However, this is just some educated guesswork at best.

So here's my actual question:
Is there an official anouncement made, or to be made, about the date or season that the new driving cycle will be implemented?
And is it known which driving cycle, or at least what kind of cycle, will be used?

Comment: I cannot answer this question. In the USA we are using the FTP06. In use since 2006. There are no plans that I know of to change the Drive Cycle. There have been calls to change the procedures so that the manufacturers much more carefully checked for test protocol violations.

Comment: @FredWilson In Europe we're still using NEDC, since '92 afaik. The cycle itself is even older, partially.